# How to migrate from Qt Creator to other IDEs, like Eclipse and Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, ide

I'm trying to develop a toolbox for System Identification and some other Engineering problems. I've managed to write source codes in C++ and they seem to be functional.

Now I'm trying to create some GUI using Qt Creator. Using some tutorials I've found using Qt very simple, but I'm not sure what happens if I decide to change my IDE for some reasons.

In my code there are a lot of code lines specific to Qt 
like: QtWidgets/QApplication, QtWidgets/QLabel, ...

As a newbie in programming could someone explain me if there are some standard methods for migrating from Qt Creator to other IDEs.

Comment: QtCreator is an IDE. Qt is a framework. Your code is never dependent on your IDE. Your code is compiled using a compiler, which doesn't depend on the IDE either. --- Sorry, as you're a newbie, you might now be confused more than before. ;) To put it simple: don't be afraid, simply use your choice of IDE now. You can switch later.

Comment: @leemes: Thanks for quick respond, But i don't get it. What about those #include QtWidgets/QLabel code lines, How they do not depend on Qt?

Comment: They depend on Qt. But not on QtCreator. Think of QtCreator being independent of Qt (in this regard). It is an IDE which uses Qt and is made for developing Qt apps. But Qt apps **can** be developed or built **without** it. Qt itself is basically "just" a set of libraries, and they don't depend on the IDE being used to develop the program. --- If you like analogies: When building a (physical) product, think of Qt being the material you build it out of; think of QtCreator being the tool. You can use different tools to build the same product with the same materials. You don't depend on the tools.

Comment: Migrating from Creator to another IDE seems like quite the bad idea. It is miles ahead of Eclipse, even more so from CodeBlocks.

As for GUI, you don't really have to use the editor, you can just as well build the UI in code.

Comment: @ddriver : I was almost happy with leemes comment, But I've seen your comment just right now. Could you explain a little more? what about leemes comment?

Comment: @eulerleibniz - nobody is forcing you to use Creator, but it is good, it is designed to work well with C++, Qt and QML, it works on every platform, is well supported so there are really no valid reasons not to use it. Eclipse is not bad, but it is not centered on Qt development and doesn't have all of its tools that make using Qt easier, and also Ecplise is written in Java and quite laggy in my experience. As for CodeBlocks - who uses that? I know more people who use Notepad, I pretty much consider it a dead end IDE. As for UI, there might be an Eclipse plugin, I know there is one for VS.

Comment: @ddriver - thanks for quick respond. but i'm not talking about IDEs functionality. I'v found Qt to be really great, but i'm not sure about it's future and specifically it's licensing stuff. Now please explain if there is some standard procedure for migrating.

Comment: Licensing should only concern you in regard with the framework itself, Creator is irrelevant. It doesn't really matter what IDE you use for your Qt application. I don't understand what kind of "migration concerns" you are having.